# How to fix an status 429 error even when calling an API once?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use [this API](https://ll.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/config/spacecraft/) to obtain information about space shuttles. I used axios to get information about the space crafts, but I get a Status 429 error. I researched, and found out that a status 429 error means that you called the API too many times, but I only called in once in my code... Could you please give me advice for solving this problem?

Code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Alert, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class SpaceCraftScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      spaceCraftData: {}
    }
  }

  getSpaceCraftData = async () => {
    axios
      .get("https://ll.thespacedevs.com/2.2.0/config/spacecraft/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({spaceCraftData:response.data.results})
        console.log(this.state.spaceCraftData)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Alert.alert(error.message)
      })
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getSpaceCraftData()
    //setInterval(() => {this.getSpaceCraftData()}, 10000)
    
  }
  render() {
    if(Object.keys(this.state.spaceCraftData).length === 0) {
      return(
        <View>
          <Text style = {{textAlign:'center', marginTop:50, fontSize:50, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Loading data</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
    else {
      let craftArray = Object.keys(this.state.spaceCraftData).map(craftData => {
        return this.state.spaceCraftData[craftData]
      })
      let spaceCrafts = [].concat.apply([], craftArray)

      spaceCrafts.sort(function(a,b) {
        a.agency.founding_year - b.agency.founding_year
      })
      console.log("SpaceCrafts: "+spaceCrafts)
      spaceCrafts.slice(0,10)
      return(
        <View>

        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try to alter your `componentDidMount` function a bit:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  if (!Object.keys(this.state.spaceCraftData).length) {
    this.getSpaceCraftData();
  }
}
```

The reason your axios call is repeating infinitely, is because you update your state inside the `getSpaceCraftData` function, so you trigger a re-render of your component. When the component mounts again it executes the `getSpaceCraftData` function again and the state is updated again, and so on.

By adding a condition that executes the function only if there is no data, then you should put an end to the execution. However this is not a complete solution, since you would need to store a state for errors as well and the condition should test if there is no error as well. If an error is encountered then you will still get an infinite loop, because there will be no data and the fetching process will probably always fail.